# Coloring in shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Im trying to draw this

[image]

I could only manage to get the lines, but I am not able to fill the shape.This is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1},scale =0.4]

        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3/2]
            \draw (0:2) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360}
            {-- (\x:2)}-- cycle (90:2)  ;
        \end{scope}
        \path[fill=blue!60] (-2,0) arc (180:0:2) -- (2,0);
        \path[fill=blue!60] (-2,0) arc (180:240:2) -- (0,0);
     \draw
        (180:2) -- (0:2)
        (240:2) -- (60:1.95)
        (300:2) -- (120:1.95);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of zillions of ways of doing this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
scale =0.4,pics/trian/.style={code={\draw[pic actions]
 (0,0) -- (-30:1) -- (30:1) -- cycle;}}]
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-3/2]
  \draw (0:2) foreach \X in {0,...,5}
  {pic[rotate=60*\X+30,/utils/exec=\ifnum\X>1 \tikzset{fill=blue!60} \fi]  {trian}
   };
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a build using the [turn] option:

The [turn] `([turn]120:2)` option rotates the line 120 to the left in the direction of the tangent to the constructed path.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1},scale =0.4]
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3/2]
        % colouring 
         \foreach \x in {120,180,...,300}
            \fill[blue!60]   (0:0)-- (\x:2)--([turn]120:2);
        % drawing     
           \foreach \x in {0,60,120,...,300}
            \draw (0:0)-- (\x:2)--([turn]120:2);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

just for fun, a version with some simplification tricks of repeating things that tikz has, and obtaining colors from more common models such as html for example.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{B}{HTML}{2E79B2}
\definecolor{W}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\def\Size{0.5cm}
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {B,W,W,B,B,B}{
    \draw[line join=round,fill=\i](0,0)--(60*\j:\Size)--++(-120+60*\j:\Size) -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```